# Domain name attached to S3, application server on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, architecture

I've been given a task to set up a website, and I've done pretty well on creating an application on an EC2 server, but the issue is we don't want to use that address for people, and the current address we want to use is attached to an S3 bucket. What's the most graceful way to achieve this?

Comment: Hey, can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do.  Maybe show an example using made-up domain names.  That will help.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for Server Fault.  Consider deleting from SO and posting over there.

Comment: Tips for asking a good question: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CloudFront distribution. Point the DNS name to the CloudFront distribution. Create two origins inside the CloudFront distribution, one pointing to the S3 bucket and the other pointing to the EC2 server.

Note that you will need to be able to configure the CloudFront distribution to understand which paths will need to be served by S3, and which paths will be served by EC2.